# How to programmatically transition between routes using Ember.js' new Router

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

### Question:

How do you do programmatically transition to a new route using the new Ember.js Router?

### Background / Context

With the old Ember.js Router you could programmatically transition between routes/states using the router's `send` method:

```
//OLD Router Syntax
App = Ember.Application.create({
  Router: Ember.Router.extend({
    root: Ember.Route.extend({
      aRoute: Ember.Route.extend({
        route: '/',
        moveElsewhere: Ember.Route.transitionTo('bRoute')
      }),
      bRoute: Ember.Route.extend({
        route: '/someOtherLocation'
      })
    })
  })
});
App.initialize();
```

Programatic Transition:

```
App.get('router').send('moveElsewhere');
```

Given the new Ember.js Router (below) how do we accomplish the same thing?

```
//NEW Router Syntax
App.Router.map(function(match) {
  match('/').to('aRoute');
  match('/someOtherLocation').to('bRoute');
});
```

### Work Around (Bad Solution?)

this can't be right, right?:

```
window.location = window.location.href + "#/someOtherLocation";
```

### Solutions that don't seem to work with the New Router:

**1)** calling the `send` method on the `App.router` instance

```
> App.router.send("moveElseWhere")
TypeError: Cannot call method 'send' of undefined
```

**2)** Explicitly declaring the Route and setting an event

```
App.ARoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  events: {
    moveElseWhere: function(context){
       this.transitionTo('bRoute');
    }
  }
);

App.UploadRoute.moveElseWhere()
TypeError: Object (subclass of Ember.Route) has no method 'moveElseWhere'
```

---

*Note: At time of writing the [Ember.js Router documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Router.html) still refers to the Old Router, where as the [Ember.js Router guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/) refers to the new Router*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14166995/access-instance-of-new-ember-router

Answer (score 9):

Assuming this Router definition:

```
App.Router.map ->
  this.resource('old_route', {path : ""})
  this.resource('new_route', {path : ":model_id"})
```

you can move to the `new_route` with the `old_route.transitionToRoute()` function when you have the controller as the context.

#### From the controller

```
this.get('target').transitionToRoute('new_route', model_instance)
```

`this.get('target')` - returns the current route from the controller

#### From a view

```
this.get('controller').get('target').transitionToRoute('activity_detail', activity)
```

#### Note

The function *transitionTo() has been [deprecated](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/2504/files) in 1.0.0.RC3

Comment: It looks like you no longer need to do a `get("target")` the `transitionToRoute` function is accessible directly from the controller itself.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `transitionTo` with the new router API, but you have to access the router instance differently.

See the answer of question [Access instance of new Ember Router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14166995/access-instance-of-new-ember-router) for the possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

you trigger a link to a new route with the {{linkTo}} helper:

```
#your template

{{#linkTo allTodos activeClass="selected"}}All{{/linkTo}}

#your router

    App.Router.map(function (match) {
        match("/").to("todos", function (match) {
            match("/").to("allTodos"); // will fire this router
            match("/active").to("activeTodos");
            match("/completed").to("completedTodos");
        });
    });
```

Hope this helps :)