# Using the new Ember RouterV2, how do you immediately redirect to another state from the index state?

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

What I have so far:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
    LOG_TRANSITIONS: true
});


App.Router.map(function(match){
    match('/').to('application');
    match('/edit').to('edit');
});


App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    redirect: function() {
        this.transitionTo('edit');
    },
    events: {
        startEdit: function( context ){
            this.transitionTo( 'edit' );
        }
    }
})

App.EditRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    init: function(){
        this._super()
        console.log('EditRoute')
    },
});
```

Handlebars:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name = 'application'>
    Hello World
    {{ outlet main }} 
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name = 'edit'>
    <div class = 'edit-background'> Edit State: {{ title }} </div>
</script>
```

I have four questions:

1. When I open the application it just remains in the home page, is the redirectTo hook suppose to immediately redirect you to another state?
2. In addition, I have this events hash in `AplicationRoute` per suggestion from here: [How to programmatically transition between routes using Ember.js' new Router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14186092/how-to-programmatically-transition-between-routes-using-ember-js-new-router). but I read through the answers and still am not sure how you are supposed to use it.
3. How do I test the router on the console? before you could navigate between the states by calling `transitionTo` commands, what do I do now?
4. For some odd reason, my application template seem to rendered twice, as in there are two 'Hello World' up there, and when try to add something like: `<li>{{#linkTo edit}}edit{{/linkTo}}</li>`

I get this error:

```
'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'container' of undefined   --  ember.js:2223'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you would initially load the editView/route/template on application start up:

## Router

```
App.Router.map(function(match){
  match('/').to('application',function(match){
    match('/').to('edit')
  })
})
```

## ApplicationTemplate

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
    {{outlet}}
</script>
```

## EditTemplate

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="edit">
    I am embedded! 
</script>
```

## EditRoute

```
EditRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  renderTemplates:function () {
      this.render('edit', {
      into:'application'
   });
})
```